Looking up values from a diiferent index to the one being searched
Let's say we have an index for Jobs to be carried out called "jobs". In this index there is a field called localityId which is a string that represnets where the job location is. This string is defined in another index called localities which when looked up gives us the polygon information.
What we would like to do is something like this: Include the Job document in the results if the Locality represented in the Jobs index(by its LocalityId) by looking it up in the localities index (where the polygon is defined for the locality) intersects the circle:
 filters.Add(fq => fq
.GeoShape(g => g.Shape(b => b.Circle(pro.Location, pro.OperationRadius.ToString()))
.Relation(GeoShapeRelation.Intersects)
.IndexedShape(f => f.Id(LocationId)
.Index("localities")
.Path("locationShape")
)));

But the problem is that we have to provide a single Id (localityId) as opposed to the localityId of each record being evaluated in the jobs index.
Is there any way we can achieve this?

Tldr;
You may not do it in a single request, if you have 2 indices.
To Solve
2 requests back to back
You will need to first retrieved from the intersection of the circles in the localities index.
From this query you will be able to get the LocalityIds that match this intersection, and use them to query for jobs with those values.
Single request, single index
If you wish to do it in a single request you need to create a single index, with each documents containing both the location and the job info. Which we lead to data deduplication. But that's fairly standards in NoSQL databases.

Hi we already knew this way, but were looking for a way of doing it by simulating a join somehow (as ES does not have a native way of doing it) or a multisearch so that we can accomplish this in one go. Thanks

As far as I know no join are possible.

I believe the answer is what Paulo is suggesting. If the platform you are making the request to doesn't have the design to support such thing, then you need to make two request because you are talking about two indexes.
A solution I can think of is that you can download or have a local version of the location index, that you use to parse the result from the job index. This way you will only make one request and then aid your result with the local location index.

@Bladfimir As shown in my snippet there are possibilities of using 2 indexes for look ups that is what I needed to be bale to do as opposed to 2 queries or creating additional indicies.
